# RDP in 2 different operating systems from outside the network

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

I have purchased a static ip from my ISP. I have two machines 1 is `windows7 (computer)` and the 2nd is `windows server 2008 R2 (laptop)`.

I have done port forwarding in my router like this: `TCP - 192.168.2.1 - 2020(port) - (WINDOWS7 Computer)` `TCP - 192.168.2.2 - 3030(port) - (Windows Server - Laptop)`

Now, i want to go to windows server 2008 directly from outside the network via RDP connection.

While doing RDP from outside the network in typing `xxx.xx.xx.xx:3030`

Please help, what i am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

You will either need a router that allows forwarding to a different (internal) port than the port it's answering on, and set that internal port to the default RDP port (3389).

(Related SU question: [Port Forwarding on Router using same internal port number on different IP addresses](https://superuser.com/questions/825188/port-forwarding-on-router-using-same-internal-port-number-on-different-ip-addres))

OR you need to change the port RDP listens on, on each machine. 
For that, see this other SU question: [How do I change the RDP listening port?](https://superuser.com/questions/63107/how-do-i-change-the-rdp-listening-port)

Also don't forget about your Firewall:

[Unable to RDP to a second computer on the same router after changing default RDP Listening Port](https://superuser.com/questions/207131/unable-to-rdp-to-a-second-computer-on-the-same-router-after-changing-default-rdp)

Comment: Thanx @Techie007 for quick reply. I can successfully login on computer1 from outside the network via RDP connection. What i need is that i want to login to computer2 from outside the network. One more thing my computer2 is on `wifi` there is no cable connected to computer2 is that okay.?

Comment: "What i need is that i want to login to computer2 from outside the network.":  Yup, and the info contained in my answer will help you achieve that. :)  "...computer2 is on wifi...": Shouldn't matter.

Comment: Okay i have configured static ip to computer2 and i can make RDP connection to computer2 successfully but from within the network. It is not working from outside the network. (And one more thing, i am trying to PING to computer2 from computer1 and i am getting `Request time out`)